# SemanticUI modal not onDeny/onApprove events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I have problem with SemanticUI modal panel module, I have set everything up, but I do not know what should I do to make onDeny/onApprove events fire. Other events as onShow and onVisible are firing properly without any problems. Also, the closable flag is set to false, but I still see close button.

My jquery listener is defined like this:

```
$('#btnReset').click(function(){
  $('#confirmModalPanel')
    .modal({
        closable  : false,
        onShow: function(){console.log('onShow');},
        onVisible: function(){console.log('onVisible');},
        onDeny: function(){console.log('onDeny');},
        onApprove: function(){console.log('onApprove');}
    })
    .modal('show');
});
```

Here is jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hjahnvmk/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close button is shown because you're adding `<i class="close icon"></i>` in your modal, if you remove this element the close button doesn't appear.

`closable` property doesn't affect in the way you expect, `closable:false` make that click anywhere out of your modal has not effect so the modal doesn't hide, alternatively if you set `closable:true` then click out of your modal makes the modal hide.

About fire `onDeny/onApprove` events you've to add `ok` class on approve `<div>` and `cancel` class on deny `<div>`. So use:

```
<div class="ui green ok basic inverted button"> // added "ok"
    <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
      DA
</div>
<div class="ui red cancel basic inverted button"> // addded "cancel"
   <i class="remove icon"></i>
      NE
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="ui green basic inverted button"> // without "ok" onApprove doesn't fires
    <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
      DA
</div>
<div class="ui red cancel basic inverted button"> // without "cancel" onDeny doesn't fire
   <i class="remove icon"></i>
      NE
</div>
```

You can also use `positive/approve`, `negative/deny` as `ok/cancel` as you see from [`semantic-ui` example:](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#approve--deny-callbacks)

> Modals will automatically tie approve deny callbacks to any
>   positive/approve, negative/deny or ok/cancel buttons.

See this working <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjahnvmk/4/)</kbd>

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you very much, those classes where the missing part, but I copied modal panel html from semantic-ui docs, and was almost sure that I was mistaking somewhere in js. You saved me a lot of time, thanks once again :)

Comment: @StefanKostic right the class names to use for approve/deny are not very clear in the documentation, nice to help you `:)`